# Adding songs to Apple Ipod from computer

Tags: linux, mp3, ipod

Actually I have **apple Ipod** and I have list of **mp3** songs in my computer. But I do not know, how to add my songs into my apple Ipod. Please help me out of this problem....I am doing this in my linux system.

Thanks

Comment: move your post on superuser ;)

Answer (score 1):

Several programms like Amarok, Rhythmbox, and gtkpod are all capable of this. You have to mount the IPod like a normal medium and than choose one of these programms.
This [articel](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPod) is quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

[GtkPod](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Home)